# Replace multiple strings in multiple documents

Tags: powershell

I am having issues with my code.  It will run and count the documents and change some information in my documents but it doesn't change all of the information. Is there something that I am missing? I have found and tried some other codes but all they seem to do is corrupt my files.  I would like to throw out there that this is my first look at PowerShell, so I pretty much suck at it.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
$folderPath = "Location of files" 
$fileType = "*.doc*" 

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false

Function findAndReplace($Text, $Find, $ReplaceWith) {
    $matchCase = $true
    $matchWholeWord = $true
    $matchWildcards = $false
    $matchSoundsLike = $false
    $matchAllWordForms = $false
    $forward = $true
    $findWrap = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace]::wdReplaceAll
    $format = $false
    $replace = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue

    $Text.Execute($Find, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, $matchWildCards, ` 
                  $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, $forward, $findWrap, `  
                  $format, $ReplaceWith, $replace) > $null
}
Function findAndReplaceWholeDoc($Document, $Find, $ReplaceWith) {
    $findReplace = $Document.Ac
    findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
    ForEach ($section in $Document.Sections) {
        ForEach ($header in $section.Headers) {
            $findReplace = $header.Range.Find
            findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
            $header.Shapes | ForEach-Object {
                if ($_.Type -eq [Microsoft.Office.Core.msoShapeType]::msoTextBox) {
                    $findReplace = $_.TextFrame.TextRange.Find
                    findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
                }
            }
        }
        ForEach ($footer in $section.Footers) {
            $findReplace = $footer.Range.Find
            findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
        }



Function processDoc {
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
    findAndReplaceWholeDoc -Document $doc -Find "Original Word" -ReplaceWith "Replacement Word"
    $doc.Close([ref]$true)
}

$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$count = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Recurse -Filter $fileType | ForEach-Object { 
  Write-Host "Processing \`"$($_.Name)\`"..."
  processDoc
  $count++
}
$sw.Stop()
$elapsed = $sw.Elapsed.toString()
Write-Host "`nDone. $count files processed in $elapsed" 

$word.Quit()
$word = $null
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: The function findAndReplaceWholeDoc is syntactically not correct. Can you please fix it and give an example what to enter into a word to reproduce the issue?